# Counter not working in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I am trying to run my counter for 3 times. once I reach 3 tries the button is supposed to be disabled. I tried couple variations of this solution to no avail. the issue is right on my rollItAgain function. I have my counter starting at 3, and a for loop with an if statement inside. I am also running my randomFunction() inside my if statement, not sure if this is good practice. As of now, I only click reroll once and it gets disabled. I would like it to run at least 3 times.

```js
// 'use strict';
var array = [];

var random = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9);
var newStars = "<div class='star'><img src='http://i.imgur.com/kXH65I7.png'></div>";

$(document).ready(init);

function init(){
 for (var i = 0; i < random; i++){
  $('#starbox').append(newStars);
  //Create Event Handler for selectNumbers Function  
 }
 $('.numbers').click(selectNumbers);
 $('#checked').click(confirm);
 $('.numbers').click(toggleButton);
 $('#playagain').click(playItAgain);
 $('#reroll').click(rollItAgain);

}

function randomFunction(){
 $('#starbox').empty();
 random = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9);
 for (var i = 0; i < random; i++){
  $('#starbox').append(newStars);
 }
} 

//selectNumbers function
function selectNumbers(){
 var num  = $(this).text();
 // $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
 array.push(num);
 // console.log(array);
 sum = array.reduce(function(a, b){
  return Number(a) + Number(b);
 });
 console.log(sum);
 //Check if numbers has select class
 console.log(num);
}


function toggleButton(){
 
 $(this).toggleClass('select');

}

function confirm(){
 if (sum === random){
  $('#displayResult').append("Correct!");
  // $('.select').css('display', 'none');
 } else {
  $('#displayResult').append("Wrong, try again!!");
 }

 $('.select').remove();
}

function rollItAgain(){
 // debugger;
 var counter = 3;
 // debugger;
 for (var j = 0; j < counter; j++){
  if(j === counter){
   
   randomFunction();
   counter++;
   
  } else {
   $('#reroll').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
 } 
}

function playItAgain(){

 location.reload();
}
```

```css
#numberbox {
 width: 400px;
 height: 100px;
 border: 2px solid green ;
}

.numbers {
 height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color:transparent;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    margin: 5px;
    line-height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    font-size: 30px;


}

#starbox {

 min-height: 300px;
    min-width: 400px;
    background-color:transparent;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    margin:100px 100px;

    
}

.star {
    display: inline-block;
}

.select {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Mathgame1</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="starbox"></div>
<p id="displayResult"></p>

<table id="numberbox" >
<button id="playagain">Play it Again</button>
<button id="checked">checked</button>
<button id="reroll">reroll</button>
 <tr >
  <td class="numbers">1</td>
  <td class="numbers">2</td>
  <td class="numbers">3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr >
  <td class="numbers">4</td>
  <td class="numbers">5</td>
  <td class="numbers">6</td>
 </tr>
 <tr >
  <td class="numbers">7</td>
  <td class="numbers">8</td>
  <td class="numbers">9</td>
 </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: which button do you want to get disabled after 3 times??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ask yourself why *wouldn't* this code run through three times? That's what a loop does. What you're really wanting is not a loop but just a counter. The thing that triggers the rolling is the click events, not a counting loop.

First off, you are misapplying a few concepts. You have a `counter` variable which looks to actually represent the counter *maximum*. `j` is more appropriately called your *counter*. But you need to keep track of the counter value between calls to `rollItAgain`, so declare it *outside* of your function. Then increment the counter whenever `rollItAgain` is called. You don't have to write a loop because the clicking of the button will take care of calling the function multiple times. Secondly, change your check; you want to run the random function when the counter is *less than* the limit:

```
var counter = 0;
var limit = 3;

function rollItAgain(){
    if (counter < limit) {
        randomFunction();
        counter++;
    } else {
        $('#reroll').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
}
```

Comment: Because if their values are initialized _inside_ of the function, then they'll be reset each time `rollItAgain` is called, and you only want them to be initialized once, at the beginning of the program.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is that you never get to condition `if(j === counter){` to roll dice because your iteration only goes as far as while `j < counter`. So this never happens.

Rewrite your function to as below, check demo - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/mhs6xprc/):

```
function rollItAgain() {
    // debugger;
    var counter = 3;
    // debugger;
    for (var j = 0; j <= counter; j++) {
        if (j < counter) {
            randomFunction();
        } else {
            $('#reroll').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    }
}
```